# algorithm issue - Reduce method solution desired

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have just written an algorithm that will perform the following:

1. An Array is given i.e `[1,5]`;
2. The function will unveil the numbers in between the numbers in the array;
3. The function will add both these numbers + all the numbers in between them.

Issue:

I feel that this solution is not as polished as I would wish. I have been trying to use reduce, controlling the index argument somehow, to replace the `for` statement with no success. I would like some help in how I could do that please.

````
var sumAll = (arr) => {
    let max = Math.max(...arr);
    let min = Math.min(...arr);
    let newArr = [];
    for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) { newArr.push(min++) }
    return newArr.reduce(function(a,b) {return a+b})
}

console.log(sumAll(arr))
// return 15, that is the sum of the numbers in newArr [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].```
````

Comment: The reason VSCode isn't giving errors is because you aren't using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) in VSCode, and you are not initializing the variable `i`. Use `for (let i = 0; i<max; i++)`  or `for (var i = 0; i<max; i++)` and the error will go away. Make it a habit to always use let (or var, but let is better most of the time) in for loops.

Comment: Hi there! I have just discovered this issue a few seconds ago in FCC and  have edited this post before reading your comment. Thanks so much for the advise anyway sir. Now I am just trying to use a ```reduce``` method instead of looping with ```for```. I guess that by using ```reduce``` it would turn my algorithm in a declarative statement instead of this imperative statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is simply to find the sum between two numbers, you can use the formula: `(max * (max+1) - (min) * (min-1))/2`. But this doesn't quite answer the problem of how to use function operations to solve this...

```js
var sumBetweenSpanningRange = (arr) => {
let max = Math.max(...arr);
let min = Math.min(...arr);

return (max * (max + 1) - min * (min -1)) / 2
}

console.log(sumBetweenSpanningRange([1,1,3,5]))
```

Comment: So why not take it the extra mile and put it inside a `sumAll` function that uses his 'min' and 'max' operations in your formula?  Your answer would probably be stronger than mine if you did it.

Comment: It was pretty polished to solve it with pure crude maths, in just 1 line. Thanks to ya'll for the support.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's a little unpolished, but not by much.  You say you want to replace the `for` loop with `reduce`.  But why not go the other way and replace the `reduce` method with the `for` loop:

```
function sumAll (arr) {
    let min = Math.min(...arr);
    let max = Math.max(...arr);
    let result = 0;
    for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) 
        result += i;
    return result;
}
```

This is assuming though that you want the sum of `[1,1,2]` to be 3, and not 4.  If you're expecting 4, then you've got other problems than just unpolishedness.

If you absolutely must replace `for` with `reduce`, then you can do the following:

```
function sumAll (arr) {
    let min = Math.min(...arr);
    let max = Math.max(...arr);
    return [...Array(max - min + 1).keys()]
        .map((_,i) => i + min)
        .reduce((a,b) => a + b);
}
```

But it's less clear what you're doing, so I wouldn't.